# render another view after rendering a previous view in node.js with express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am working on a node.js and express.js app.

I have router configured as:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

   // on load

   res.render('mail', { title: "this is the title." });

   // after some more funcitonality redirect/render a new view

 If(condition == 'success'){

   res.render('sent', { title: "this is the   title." });

   // or

   res.redirect('/sent');

  }


});
```

Now the problem is when I render a new view based on the condition after rendering the first view or if I redirect to a new route after rendering the first view, I get

```
Headers cannot be set after they have been sent error
```

The execution though continues but the view is not loaded and the page is not redirected.

Any help to overcome this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't redirect after you have already sent a view (page)

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Show a mail page and then change that to a 'sent' page once the message is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a second response.

Or you render a view or redirect to another route, not both.

Look in [express](http://expressjs.com/es/) for the documentation.

Comment: Quite illogical i got.  i have hadled it through ajax calls to carry out functions and return to the same view and than redirect.